# Adjust div according to inner divs

Tags: html, css

I have a set of divs going left and down, like a staircase. Maybe There's a better way for doing it, but I got it.

Now I would like to have a div around all these "stairs". something like this: 
[image]

Notice that these stairs start kind of in middle (horizontally) in the page. How can I make this outer div according to these number of stairs without having to type the height and width?

Another important note is that sometimes there are only 4 steps, which means the outter div really has to adjust according to displayed divs.

Here you have a small plunker if you want to check it out:

[PLUNKER](https://plnkr.co/edit/kEO5Jq2bpE4rFk5dwPAt?p=preview)

Here's the css stylesheet with the above mentioned "stairs"

```css
.box1 {
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid #eaeaea;
  border-radius: 2px;
  margin-left: 30%;
  width: 8%;
  height: 40px;
}

.box2 {
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: 38%;
  border: 1px solid #eaeaea;
  border-radius: 2px;
  width: 8%;
  height: 40px;
}

.box3 {
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: 46%;
  border: 1px solid #eaeaea;
  border-radius: 2px;
  width: 8%;
  height: 40px;
}

.box4 {
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: 54%;
  border: 1px solid #eaeaea;
  border-radius: 2px;
  width: 8%;
  height: 40px;
}

.box5 {
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: 62%;
  border: 1px solid #eaeaea;
  border-radius: 2px;
  width: 8%;
  height: 40px;
}

.box6 {
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: 70%;
  border: 1px solid #eaeaea;
  border-radius: 2px;
  width: 8%;
  height: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="boxContainer">
  <div class="row box1">
    hello 1
  </div>
  <div class="row box2">
    hello 2
  </div>
  <div class="row box3">
    hello 3
  </div>
  <div class="row box4">
    hello 4
  </div>
  <div class="row box5">
    hello 5
  </div>
  <div class="row box6">
    hello 6
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is it always either 6 or 4 divs? Then i would suggest to handle this with a class for the outer div.

Comment: What CSS have you tried for the outer div? Have you tried making it display as an inline-block? Have you tried using a flex layout?

Comment: Create a wrapper around those boxed divs which has style margin set to `0 auto` then use JavaScript to calculate width and padding of those boxed divs inside wrapper (based on an amount of those boxed divs) not a viewport which you are doing now.

Comment: @ThomasKleßen may vary. from 3 to 6 steps.

Comment: @kojow7 inline block wont put them all in the same line?

Comment: @JackTheKnife ultimately that's what I'll have to do, use javascript. Thank you :)

Comment: @N.Car correct. Even you can crate those divs with JavaScript loop not only adjusting styles, which is a minimum in your case.

Comment: Isn't necesary use javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if I'm fully understanding your problem. Do you mean something like this?

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.boxContainer {
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 3px solid black;
  padding: 5px 5px 5px 30px; /* Approach to OP's image */
  --steps: 6;
}

.box {
  --size: calc(100% / var(--steps));
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: var(--size);
  height: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;

}

.box:nth-child(2) {
  left: var(--size);
}

.box:nth-child(3) {
  left: calc(2 * var(--size));
}

.box:nth-child(4) {
  left: calc(3 * var(--size));
}

.box:nth-child(5) {
  left: calc(4 * var(--size));
}

.box:nth-child(6) {
  left: calc(5 * var(--size));
}
```

```html
<div class="boxContainer">
  <div class="row box">
    hello 1
  </div>
  <div class="row box">
    hello 2
  </div>
  <div class="row box">
    hello 3
  </div>
  <div class="row box">
    hello 4
  </div>
  <div class="row box">
    hello 5
  </div>
  <div class="row box">
    hello 6
  </div>
</div>
```

I've used a [Custom Property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/--*) (a.k.a. CSS variable) `--steps` so you can define how many steps will be in the `boxContainer`.

This way, if you only have 4 boxes inside the container you could overwrite this variable inline, like:

```
<div class="boxContainer" style="--steps: 4">
```

And everything would fit without any other changes on the CSS.

You can use JS to do this change or, if you're using some server-side language to generate the markup, it's even easier... e.g. in PHP:

```
<?php $boxes = ['hello 1', 'hello 2', 'hello 3', 'hello 4']; ?>
<div class="boxContainer" style="--steps: <?= count($boxes) ?>">
<?php foreach ($boxes as $box): ?>
    <div class="row box"><?= $box ?></div>
<?php endforeach ?>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried adding your css in the plunker i've created and it doesn't work like here the page?!?

Comment: Here you got a Plunker with my code, @N.Car: https://plnkr.co/edit/7VpOFhnSbZlLb3xXublo?p=preview

Comment: works perfectly. If I had a margin on the large container it all keeps inside just perfect. Thank you :)
I also found another solution using JS

Answer (score 1):

It's kinda messy, but you could try this:

```css
.row {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 80px;
  height: 25px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 100%;
  top: 100%;
}

.boxContainer {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.wrapper {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="boxContainer">
    <div class="row box1">
      <div class="wrapper">
        hello 1
      </div>
      <div class="row">
          <div class="wrapper">
            hello 2
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="wrapper">
              hello 3
            </div>
              <div class="row">
                <div class="wrapper">
                  hello 4
                </div>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This plays with the way position absolute and relative works.

Comment: Not quite like my picture. But thanks for your time. Already got an answer :)

Comment: @N.Car Well the whole point was just to get the staircase effect without using JS. Your current css relies on fixing the width whereas mine doesn't.

Comment: Yes,  its a good solution for getting the staircase :) thank you

Comment: It will be useful for when you have an unknown number of steps and don't/can't use javascript.

Answer (score 0):

You may try this:

```css
.boxContainer{
  border: solid 2px #000;
  border-radius: 8px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.box1 {
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid #eaeaea;
  border-radius: 2px;
  margin-left: 30%;
  width: 8%;
  height: 40px;
}

.box2 {
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: 38%;
  border: 1px solid #eaeaea;
  border-radius: 2px;
  width: 8%;
  height: 40px;
}

.box3 {
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: 46%;
  border: 1px solid #eaeaea;
  border-radius: 2px;
  width: 8%;
  height: 40px;
}

.box4 {
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: 54%;
  border: 1px solid #eaeaea;
  border-radius: 2px;
  width: 8%;
  height: 40px;
}

.box5 {
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: 62%;
  border: 1px solid #eaeaea;
  border-radius: 2px;
  width: 8%;
  height: 40px;
}

.box6 {
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: 70%;
  border: 1px solid #eaeaea;
  border-radius: 2px;
  width: 8%;
  height: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="boxContainer">
  <div class="row box1">
    hello 1
  </div>
  <div class="row box2">
    hello 2
  </div>
  <div class="row box3">
    hello 3
  </div>
  <div class="row box4">
    hello 4
  </div>
  <div class="row box5">
    hello 5
  </div>
  <div class="row box6">
    hello 6
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The outer box should not have the whole page width, just the stairs. Someone already gave a good answer. Thank you for your time :)